# Are there any " on leave tab " event for the fragment inside the tabhost in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-lifecycle, fragment-tab-host

I am working on the tabhost and fragment implementation. There are 5 tabs in my tabhost , I would like to implement some code (go back 1 level) whenever the user leave the tab3. However, I tried on detach and on pause , both are not working.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    super.onDetach();
}
```

So I wonder what is the activity cycle the fragment will at when the user click on the other tab? or , are there any way to capture that event ? Thanks

Comment: `TabHost` is deprecated. Use `ActionBarActivity` from the v7 support library if you need backwards compatibility. Then use `TabListener`.

Comment: would you mind provide some code example ? I have target the app on >4.0

Comment: You can create a new blank project using the Tabs + Swipe navigation template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this callback to your TabHost:

```
myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener()
{

  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
  {
     // Tab was changed; now do stuff  
  }

});
```

Comment: The program sequence is not quite correct. For example, if I am at tab3 , I press tab1, it execute the backstack function only when I leaved the tab3 , and the go backstack function will run on the tab1